# Blazor Web App: Correct Scandinavian character rendering but incorrect source HTML for dynamic content

Tags: c#, asp.net, utf-8, character-encoding, blazor

I am trying to set dynamic metadata from code section in a Blazor Web App. In my case the meta keywords sections is coming from a IStringLocalizer, but the issue can be reproduced without the localization.

If the content contains Scandinavian characters they are rendered in the source section incorrectly. For example 'ä' is shown as '&#xE4'.
If the content is set in html section characters are rendered correctly.

Note: My issue is specifically related to source files not the actual browser rendering which is correct in all cases.

Issue can be reproduced with a new Blazor Web App with following Home.razor page:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
<HeadContent>
    <meta name="description" content="ää">
    <meta name="keywords" content="@keywords">
</HeadContent>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@code
{
    private string keywords = "ää";
}
```

Produces following source file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="ää">
    <meta name="keywords" content="&#xE4;&#xE4;" />
</head>
```

It seems that my knowledge regarding Blazor is missing something fundamental and I would like to understand what is the cause for this and is there a way get it working.
Also, I am not sure if having &#xE4 characters in the source file causes any issues with SEO.

I have tried to set the keywords with MarkupString, and also tried decode the string before setting it. I also checked the file encodings and tried both: UTF-8 and UTF-8 with BOM.
I have also checked that the Content-Type in header is correct: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

```
<meta name="keywords" content="@((MarkupString)keywords)">
```

```
keywords = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("ää");
```